# How to use custom dimension to do UTM-like tracking in GA4?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4, utm, urchin

I usually used utm_source / utm_medium to tracking the purchase/revenue related performance in the past. Recently I tried to evaluate the new marketing tool and I want to know its performance. However, I don't want to adjust the original utm_source / utm_medium and I prefer use a inpendent variable UTM-like tracking, is it possible to do the purchase/revenue tracking with self-defined dimension ?

[ga_dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nCr1Y.png)

Ideally I would like to select the Custom Dimension with medium/source in the attachment pic
And I can tell the purchase/revenue of each medium/source

Last, Here is my goal : I would like to use the GA4 Data API ReportRequest function to get the metric data from each custom-dimension.

I find "See custom campaign data" described here
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/10917952?hl=en#zippy=%2Cin-this-article
but I'm not sure whether it is the clue .

Thank you for the kindly support!
Have a good day